# String "\u1110" getting converted to "?"

Tags: java, string

When I am trying something below code:

```
String x = "\u1110";
System.out.println("value of x ="+x);
```

output :

```
value of x =?
```

1. Why output is coming like this ?
2. I would like to get the output same as \u1110 ?
3. How it is representing in String pool whether \u1110 or ?.

Comment: In what environment are you trying to output it in?

Comment: I initially misread the question - I assumed that the question mark symbol was the correct interpretation of the provided unicode value.  Elliott's answer is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `String` (and `String` pool) contains "ᄐ" ([Unicode Character 'HANGUL CHOSEONG THIEUTH' (U+1110)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1110/index.htm)). But, to answer your *first* question, your console doesn't (apparently) have a glyph for that.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, Is there any way to have output as "\u1110" without appending "\" to it.? OR Is there any way to change my console to have the same?

Comment: What do you **mean** by "\u1110"? If you want a literal backslash in your `String` you need to escape it, because `'\\'` is the **escape** character (for example, `char ch = '\\';`).